# Install4j execute action group by code

Tags: java, install4j

I want to execute an action group when pressing on a button in Install4j, is this possible?

I found out that it is possible to get an action by calling `context.getActionById()`, but I can't figure out how to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
((InstallAction)action).install(context);
```

on the action returned by `context.getAction()`.

Comment: I used `getActionById` and casted it to `InstallAction` to use the `install` method. That seemded to work. Is it also possible to execute a action-group?

Comment: No, that is currently not possible.